Cannot call IntentSenderRequest.Builder() with a Boolean
This code raises the following compile error:
val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build()

None of the following candidates is applicable: constructor(intentSender: IntentSender): IntentSenderRequest. Builder constructor(pendingIntent: PendingIntent): IntentSenderRequest. Builder


Full code for more context:
package com.byteflipper.ffsensitivities.playcore

import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManagerFactory
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateOptions
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.AppUpdateType
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.UpdateAvailability
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

class InAppUpdateManager(
    private val context: Context,
    private val updateStrategy: UpdateStrategy = UpdateStrategy.AUTO,
    private val updateResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>
) {
    private val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context)
    private val currentVersionCode = getCurrentVersionCode(context)
    val updateState: MutableState<UpdateState> = mutableStateOf(UpdateState.Idle)

    enum class UpdateStrategy {
        AUTO, FLEXIBLE, IMMEDIATE
    }

    sealed class UpdateState {
        object Idle : UpdateState()
        object Checking : UpdateState()
        object Downloading : UpdateState()
        object Downloaded : UpdateState()
        data class Error(val message: String) : UpdateState()
    }

    private fun getCurrentVersionCode(context: Context): Long {
        return try {
            val packageInfo = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, 0)
            packageInfo.longVersionCode
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.e("InAppUpdateManager", "Не удалось получить версию приложения", e)
            0L
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fetchAppUpdateInfo(): com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo? {
        return try {
            appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo.await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("InAppUpdateManager", "Ошибка получения информации об обновлении", e)
            null
        }
    }

    private fun shouldStartUpdate(appUpdateInfo: com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo, updateType: Int): Boolean {
        return appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE &&
                appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(updateType)
    }

    private fun determineUpdateType(availableVersionCode: Long): Int {
        return when (updateStrategy) {
            UpdateStrategy.FLEXIBLE -> AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
            UpdateStrategy.IMMEDIATE -> AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE
            UpdateStrategy.AUTO -> {
                val versionDifference = availableVersionCode - currentVersionCode
                when {
                    versionDifference > 3 -> AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE
                    else -> AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun CheckForUpdates() {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            updateState.value = UpdateState.Checking
            val appUpdateInfo = fetchAppUpdateInfo()
            if (appUpdateInfo != null) {
                val updateType = determineUpdateType(appUpdateInfo.availableVersionCode().toLong())
                if (shouldStartUpdate(appUpdateInfo, updateType)) {
                    startUpdate(appUpdateInfo, updateType)
                } else {
                    updateState.value = UpdateState.Idle
                }
            } else {
                updateState.value = UpdateState.Error("Не удалось получить информацию об обновлении.")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startUpdate(appUpdateInfo: com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo, updateType: Int) {
        try {
            val updateOptions = AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(updateType).build()
            val intentSender = appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                context as androidx.activity.ComponentActivity,
                updateOptions,
                UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
            )
            val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build()
            updateResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest)
            updateState.value = UpdateState.Downloading
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("InAppUpdateManager", "Ошибка при запуске обновления", e)
            updateState.value = UpdateState.Error(e.message ?: "Неизвестная ошибка")
        }
    }

    fun completeUpdate() {
        appUpdateManager.completeUpdate()
        updateState.value = UpdateState.Downloaded
    }

    companion object {
        const val UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE = 100
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

AppUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult() returns a boolean, not an IntentSender. Your code:
        val updateOptions = AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(updateType).build()
        val intentSender = appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
            appUpdateInfo,
            context as androidx.activity.ComponentActivity,
            updateOptions,
            UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
        )
        val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build()

seems to expect that it returns an IntentSender.
Check the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateManager.html#startUpdateFlowForResult(com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo,%20android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateOptions,%20int)

Before calling
    val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build()

you are using this method:
val intentSender = appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                context as androidx.activity.ComponentActivity,
                updateOptions,
                UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
            )

As can be seen in the documentation, this method returns a boolean.
That is why you are getting the error

Cannot call IntentSenderRequest.Builder() with a Boolean

To create an IntentSender object you can't do it directly, but rather from an existing PendingIntent with PendingIntent.getIntentSender().
Reference
